# Given arbitrary $c$, which $n$ satisfies $\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac1k<c≤\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac1k$?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Everyone knows that the harmonic series $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1k$$

is a monotonically-increasing divergent series. This should imply, I think, that for all $c>1$ there exists some natural $N$ such that for all $n≥N$ $$\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1k>c$$

for otherwise the harmonic series would be bounded above by $c$ and hence would converge to its supremum which would be a contradiction.

My question is this: suppose we have some arbitrary $c$. Is there an explicit formula by which we can determine which $n$ satisfies ...

$$\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac1k<c≤\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac1k$$

..?

As an example, for $c=8$ it would be $1674$.

Comment: We can find an *approximate* solution, using the fact that $\sum_1^n \frac{1}{k}\approx \log n+\gamma$ (the Euler-Mascheroni constant).

Comment: Exercise :For $n\geq 2$ the value of $\sum_{j=1}^n1/j$  is not  an integer.

Comment: @user254665 In the OP, $c$ is arbitrary and bounded by consecutive sequence of partial sums.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By $H_{n}=\ln n +\gamma +\frac{1}{2n}+O(\frac{1}{n^{2}})$, then
$H_{n-1}=\ln n +\gamma -\frac{1}{2n}+O(\frac{1}{n^{2}})$

For some reasonable $c$, we want to find an $n\in \mathbf{N}$ such that
$H_{n-1} < c < H_{n}$, we have
$$\ln n +\gamma -\frac{1}{2n} < c < \ln n +\gamma +\frac{1}{2n}$$
$$\ln n -\frac{1}{2n} < c -\gamma < \ln n +\frac{1}{2n}$$
$$n\exp \left(-\frac{1}{2n} \right) < e^{c -\gamma} < n\exp \left(\frac{1}{2n} \right) $$
$$n\left(1-\frac{1}{2n} \right) \lesssim e^{c -\gamma} \lesssim n\left(1+\frac{1}{2n} \right) $$
$$e^{c -\gamma}-\frac{1}{2} \lesssim n \lesssim e^{c -\gamma}+\frac{1}{2} $$